# Verify if user has purchased a product (iAP) in the past

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, in-app-purchase

I have a popular app (over 400k downloads), the project started 4 years ago as a 'fun' project. We implemented ads and users could remove them for $0,99. Now, 4 years later the app is pretty popular and we want to change our business model a bit, from $0,99 once to $1,59 every year. Currently i'm experiencing a little problem with in app purchase on iOS:

I want to give people who purchased the iAP in the past another free year after they restored the old product but when i call "RestorePreviousPurchases" (i'm using Xamarin for the new App, was Objective-c in the old version) it gives me a callback when when the product was restored, but when the user did not purchase the old product i'm not getting a callback. Is this intentionally done by Apple?

Are there any ways to verify if the product was purchased OR NOT (the most important part). I need some sort of callback when the user did not purchase any product. Any best practices? It's driving me crazy ;)

Comment: This sounds more like a Xamarin thing than an Apple thing. In standard store kit processing when you initiate a restore, any previous purchases are presented to your payment queue transaction observer and you can processes these much the same as you would an initial purchase. Once restoration has completed you get a call to `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`.